# Android java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, android, time

I am coding an Android application, which should receive a java.time.LocalDateTime object through an HTTP REST API that I developed in the server side.

The problem is that Android is still in Java 7, and java.time is only available in Java 8.

Having that said, what is the best way to represent a variable that contains date and time in Android? I prefer not to use sql.timestamp.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother you using `Date` or `Calendar` previous to Java 8 while the Android version of Joda-time (that is very close from the Java 8 dates) is available ?

Here is the GIT repo/website for more information :

https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android

Comment: The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, and further adapted to Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Comment: @Basil Bourque Thank you for these precisions.

Comment: Joda time library adds about 5k methods

Answer (score 5):

## Back-port

You could use the [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which is an Android adaption to the original [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) that backports much of the new `java.time` api back to Java SE 6 and SE 7.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) to get started.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LocalDateTime if your minSdkVersion is 26 (Android 8.0) or higher [1](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime). Otherwise, you can use [core library desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring).

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

Comment: hello, yes I see im implementing this option and runs well but when I run it on a lower version of API 26 crashes because does not find LocalDateTime, what would you do in this case? implement threaten?

Comment: I have used this extensively and it works well on older Android versions. Did you set `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true` in all of your modules?

Comment: ahhhh, yes, Im developing a Library (not experienced on them) but yes I see this flag should be added to the app module that implements the library as well, thank you colleague.

Answer (score 1):

Use the java.util.Calendar which is available in Java 7. Refer to the link below for more information:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance(); //initialized with the current date and time
```

Comment: The troublesome old date-time classes such as `Calendar` are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, and further adapted to Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score 0):

a `LocalDateTime` object has been serialized to a `string`|`long` JSON property through an HTTP REST API.

so you just to do is adaptee the JSON property to a `Date` object, and format a `Date` object to the JSON property if you want to send a `Date` object to the server which only accept a `LocalDateTime` object.

almost all the JSON library providing a `dateFormat` for serializing/deserializing a `string` to a `Date`,
and convert long `timestamp` to `Date` is so simple:

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
```

Comment: Date(java.lang.String) is deprecated as of API 16: Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean)