# Kotlin: Convert date string to ISO string

Tags: java, date, kotlin

I have a date String with following format: `MM/DD/2019`
Possible values could be `1/16/2019` or `11/31/2019` for example.

I'm searching a way to convert this String values to get the following format:

```
2019-11-31 15:07:57.013Z
```

How can I do that in Kotlin ?

Comment: https://www.codevscolor.com/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-in-kotlin/

Comment: Why should `11/31/2019` be a possible value?

Comment: How do you want to add the time part if you only get dates to be parsed?

Comment: Regarding your title, the format you want is not ISO. *Separating date and time parts with other characters such as space is not allowed in ISO 8601,…* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations))

Answer (score 6):

One of the great things of Kotlin is that you can reuse Java libraries, so  `java.time` library can be used like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

class ApplicationTests {
    @Test
    fun changeDateFormat(){
        val inputDateString = "11/31/2019"
        val inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
        val localDate = LocalDate.parse(inputDateString, inputFormatter)
        val outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
        val localDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay()
        val zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
        val outputDateString = outputFormatter.format(zonedDateTime)
        print(outputDateString)
    }
}
```

Running that test will print `2019-12-01 00:00:00.000-0500` as output.

The new format has hours and minutes, so the `LocalDate` needs to be transformed into a `LocalDateTime`, and that can be done by `atStartOfDay()`, as an option there's `atTime(H,M)`.

The new format also has a timezone, for that you need to transform it to `ZonedDateTime`  the method `.atZone(..)`  can be used for that.

---

`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` could also be used in a couple of lines:

```
val date = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("11/31/2019")
print(SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(date))
```

But as @OleV.V. pointed out it's quite outdated and has some troubles (like not taking the time and timezone into account might be leading to undesired bugs).

Comment: @OleV.V. you're right, I updated it to use `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: In Android `DateTimeFormatter` requires API 26, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999112/date-and-time-in-android-studio-kotlin-language.

Comment: @CoolMind follow this and it will allow you to have backward compatibility with older version https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Comment: @MihaeKheel, thanks, a good advice.

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to this for ISO format conversion: https://mincong-h.github.io/2017/02/16/convert-date-to-string-in-java/

```
    String dateStr = "1/16/2019";

    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(dateStr);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    String dateText = sdf.format(date);

    System.out.println(dateText);
```

Comment: These date-time classes are terrible. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: It is a preferrable solution for Android, because `DateTimeFormatter` requires API 26, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999112/date-and-time-in-android-studio-kotlin-language.

Answer (score 4):

By using a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) you can indicate in what format you provide the dates or expect the dates.

See it online: https://ideone.com/jDhi4x

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.Locale

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val string = "1/16/2019"
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val date = LocalDate.parse(string, formatter)
    println(date)
}
```

Comment: Limited to SDK 26 and above only, for backward compatibility on older devices follow this https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring